Pycharm can't connect to jupyter
When I run a .ipynb file in Pycharm, I see the following error:
[I 2024-10-03 00:41:28.291 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 2.14.1 is running at:
[I 2024-10-03 00:41:28.291 ServerApp] http://localhost:8888/tree?token=e6a3be099716e2beeea9277aee4fb246ee21279672ec92e6
[I 2024-10-03 00:41:28.291 ServerApp]     http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=e6a3be099716e2beeea9277aee4fb246ee21279672ec92e6
[I 2024-10-03 00:41:28.291 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2024-10-03 00:41:28.294 ServerApp] 
    
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///Users/timtan/Library/Jupyter/runtime/jpserver-44104-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/tree?token=e6a3be099716e2beeea9277aee4fb246ee21279672ec92e6
        http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=e6a3be099716e2beeea9277aee4fb246ee21279672ec92e6
[I 2024-10-03 00:41:28.306 ServerApp] Skipped non-installed server(s): bash-language-server, dockerfile-language-server-nodejs, javascript-typescript-langserver, jedi-language-server, julia-language-server, pyright, python-language-server, python-lsp-server, r-languageserver, sql-language-server, texlab, typescript-language-server, unified-language-server, vscode-css-languageserver-bin, vscode-html-languageserver-bin, vscode-json-languageserver-bin, yaml-language-server
[W 2024-10-03 00:41:41.887 ServerApp] wrote error: 'Forbidden'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/timtan/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1788, in _execute
        result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
      File "/Users/timtan/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 3289, in wrapper
        url = self.get_login_url()
      File "/Users/timtan/opt/anaconda3/envs/pythonProject1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 783, in get_login_url
        raise web.HTTPError(403)
    tornado.web.HTTPError: HTTP 403: Forbidden

I can access the follow links in chrome:
http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree?token=e6a3be099716e2beeea9277aee4fb246ee21279672ec92e6 
http://localhost:8888/tree?token=e6a3be099716e2beeea9277aee4fb246ee21279672ec92e6
And ther version of the packages:
anyio   3.7.1   
appnope 0.1.2   
argon2-cffi 21.3.0  
argon2-cffi-bindings    21.2.0  
arrow   1.3.0   
asttokens   2.0.5   
async-lru   2.0.4   
attrs   23.1.0  
babel   2.11.0  
backcall    0.2.0   
backtrader  1.9.78.123  
beautifulsoup4  4.12.3  
bleach  4.1.0   
brotli-python   1.0.9   
bzip2   1.0.8   
ca-certificates 2024.9.24   
certifi 2024.8.30   
cffi    1.17.1  
charset-normalizer  3.3.2   
comm    0.2.1   
contourpy   1.1.1   
cycler  0.12.1  
cyrus-sasl  2.1.28  
debugpy 1.6.7   
decorator   5.1.1   
defusedxml  0.7.1   
entrypoints 0.4 
exceptiongroup  1.2.0   
executing   0.8.3   
fonttools   4.54.1  
fqdn    1.5.1   
gettext 0.21.0  
glib    2.78.4  
glib-tools  2.78.4  
gst-plugins-base    1.14.1  
gstreamer   1.14.1  
h11 0.14.0  
httpcore    1.0.2   
httpx   0.27.0  
icu 73.1    
idna    3.7 
importlib-metadata  7.0.1   
importlib-resources 6.4.5   
importlib_metadata  7.0.1   
importlib_resources 6.4.0   
ipykernel   6.28.0  
ipython 8.12.2  
ipython-genutils    0.2.0   
ipywidgets  8.1.2   
isoduration 20.11.0 
jedi    0.19.1  
jinja2  3.1.4   
jpeg    9e  
json5   0.9.6   
jsonpointer 3.0.0   
jsonschema  4.19.2  
jsonschema-specifications   2023.7.1    
jupyter 1.0.0   
jupyter-client  7.4.9   
jupyter-lsp 2.2.0   
jupyter-server  2.14.1  
jupyter_console 6.6.3   
jupyter_core    5.7.2   
jupyter_events  0.10.0  
jupyter_server_terminals    0.4.4   
jupyterlab  4.2.5   
jupyterlab_pygments 0.1.2   
jupyterlab_server   2.27.3  
jupyterlab_widgets  3.0.10  
kiwisolver  1.4.7   
krb5    1.20.1  
libclang    14.0.6  
libclang13  14.0.6  
libcxx  14.0.6  
libedit 3.1.20230828    
libffi  3.4.4   
libglib 2.78.4  
libiconv    1.16    
libllvm14   14.0.6  
libpng  1.6.39  
libpq   12.17   
libsodium   1.0.18  
libxml2 2.13.1  
llvm-openmp 14.0.6  
lz4-c   1.9.4   
markupsafe  2.1.3   
matplotlib  3.2.2   
matplotlib-inline   0.1.6   
mistune 2.0.4   
mysql   5.7.24  
nbclassic   1.1.0   
nbclient    0.8.0   
nbconvert   7.10.0  
nbformat    5.9.2   
ncurses 6.4 
nest-asyncio    1.6.0   
notebook    7.2.2   
notebook-shim   0.2.3   
numpy   1.24.4  
openssl 3.0.15  
overrides   7.4.0   
packaging   24.1    
pandas  2.0.3   
pandocfilters   1.5.0   
parso   0.8.3   
pcre2   10.42   
pexpect 4.8.0   
pickleshare 0.7.5   
pillow  10.4.0  
pip 24.2    
pkgutil-resolve-name    1.3.10  
platformdirs    3.10.0  
ply 3.11    
prometheus_client   0.14.1  
prompt-toolkit  3.0.43  
prompt_toolkit  3.0.43  
psutil  5.9.0   
ptyprocess  0.7.0   
pure_eval   0.2.2   
pycparser   2.21    
pygments    2.15.1  
pyparsing   3.1.4   
pyqt    5.15.10 
pyqt5-sip   12.13.0 
pysocks 1.7.1   
python  3.8.19  
python-dateutil 2.9.0post0  
python-fastjsonschema   2.16.2  
python-json-logger  2.0.7   
pytz    2024.2  
pyyaml  6.0.1   
pyzmq   24.0.1  
qt-main 5.15.2  
qtconsole   5.6.0   
qtpy    2.4.1   
readline    8.2 
referencing 0.30.2  
requests    2.32.3  
rfc3339-validator   0.1.4   
rfc3986-validator   0.1.1   
rpds-py 0.10.6  
send2trash  1.8.2   
setuptools  75.1.0  
sip 6.7.12  
six 1.16.0  
sniffio 1.3.0   
soupsieve   2.5 
sqlite  3.45.3  
stack_data  0.2.0   
ta-lib  0.4.32  
terminado   0.17.1  
tinycss2    1.2.1   
tk  8.6.14  
tomli   2.0.1   
tornado 6.4.1   
traitlets   5.14.3  
types-python-dateutil   2.9.0.20240906  
typing-extensions   4.11.0  
typing_extensions   4.11.0  
tzdata  2024.2  
uri-template    1.3.0   
urllib3 2.2.3   
wcwidth 0.2.5   
webcolors   24.8.0  
webencodings    0.5.1   
websocket-client    1.8.0   
wheel   0.44.0  
widgetsnbextension  4.0.10  
xz  5.4.6   
yaml    0.2.5   
zeromq  4.3.5   
zipp    3.20.2  
zlib    1.2.13  
zstd    1.5.5   

